# How do I make my horizontal UICollectionView cells swiping work flawlessly in a pagination manner(cells must be centered when swiped)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have a UICollectionView in my app, and the use case is that I want it to work like AppStore's Apps tab top collection view, in which swiping each cell makes the next cell centered. I have achieved that somehow in my app **without using CollectionView's paging enabled property** and did some calculation of sizes and achieved quite a good result, but it is lagging sometimes. It will be very helpful if some-one suggests a better approach to achieve the App store kind of behavior using a UICollectionView :).

**App Store Example. See how the top collectionView works.** 
[image]

Wherever, I found this type of implementation, everywhere it has been implemented with UIScrollView. But, I am in search of the exact same behavior with a UICollectionView.

**What I have achieved so far in my app.**
[image]

[image]

**See the collection View at the bottom. I have implemented this behavior using overriding the default scrollViewWillEndDragging method of scrollView from which a UICollectionView inherits and in that method, I have done the following calculations.**

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    // Stop scrollView sliding:
    targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset

    let indexOfMajorCell = self.indexOfMajorCell()

    // calculate conditions:
    let dataSourceCount = collectionView(cardsCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection: 0)
    let swipeVelocityThreshold: CGFloat = 5.0 // after some trail and error
    let hasEnoughVelocityToSlideToTheNextCell = indexOfCellBeforeDragging + 1 < dataSourceCount && velocity.x > swipeVelocityThreshold
    let hasEnoughVelocityToSlideToThePreviousCell = indexOfCellBeforeDragging - 1 >= 0 && velocity.x < -swipeVelocityThreshold
    let majorCellIsTheCellBeforeDragging = indexOfMajorCell == indexOfCellBeforeDragging
    let didUseSwipeToSkipCell = majorCellIsTheCellBeforeDragging && (hasEnoughVelocityToSlideToTheNextCell || hasEnoughVelocityToSlideToThePreviousCell)

    if didUseSwipeToSkipCell {

        let snapToIndex = indexOfCellBeforeDragging + (hasEnoughVelocityToSlideToTheNextCell ? 1 : -1)
        let toValue = collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize.width * CGFloat(snapToIndex)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: velocity.x, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: toValue, y: 0)
            scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)

    } else {
        // This is a much better way to scroll to a cell:
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: indexOfMajorCell, section: 0)
        cardsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionView!.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Note:** *The paging enabled property of the UICollectionView has been set to false in my implementation for this to work. When I turn that property to ON it was showing some weird behavior that some part of each cell becomes hidden whenever I do a swipe.*

Comment: were you able to solve this? any thoughts or examples to provide? Thanks.

Comment: Hey actually I used a library by nicklockwood and it worked like a charm.
You can try it here
**https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel**